# Clones not using animator / enabled / disabled functions?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make my enemy freeze when it gets in contact with an ice projectile. Everything works no errors except the animator doesn't play the animations and the script doesn't get enabled / disabled.
I've tried script = GetComponent(); and anim = gameObject.GetComponent(); too for that section. And for the set active ive tried script.enabled script.setactive ect ect. None of it works. I think this might have to do with the get component but IDK. These are on instantiated prefabs btw.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyHealth : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float health;

    public float freezeTime;
    public Animator anim;
    public Enemy script;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    IEnumerator Wait(){
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (freezeTime);
        Debug.Log("waiting over");
    }
    void Start()
    {
        anim = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
        script = gameObject.GetComponent<Enemy>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(health <= 0){
            Dead();
        }   
    }
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other){
        if(other.CompareTag("Harmful")){
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
            TakeDamage();
        }
        if(other.CompareTag("Freezing")){
             anim.SetBool("IsFrozen", true); 
             Destroy(other.gameObject);
             gameObject.GetComponent<Enemy>().enabled = false;
             TakeDamage();
             Debug.Log("waiting started");
             StartCoroutine(Wait());
             anim.SetBool("IsFrozen", false);
             gameObject.GetComponent<Enemy>().enabled = true;
        }
    }
    void TakeDamage(){
         health -= 1f;
    }
    void Dead(){
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: What is your goal? `Enabled` and `Disable` will change the state of a singular component on a `GameObject`. So in your example case, it is setting the script `Enemy` on and off. It would have nothing to do with the animator. If your animation is not working, then it would have to do most likely with your animation tree not being set up correctly or the animation parameter not being set correctly.

Comment: Are the animator and enemy components on the same gameObject as the enemy health script?

Comment: @hijinxbassist Yes and to disable the enemy script which does movement and attack to give the effect of a freezing effect.

Comment: To clarify I want to turn off the enemy script and the animator is just also not doing what its supposed to

Comment: These are also all clones btw.

Comment: The script seems fine, are you sure the condition is met?  It almost sounds like none of that code is running.  Have you put a debug in the `if (other.CompareTag("Freezing"))` scope to make sure that section actually executes?

Comment: Is freeze time set to a value higher than 0?  Having the default value of 0 would also cause what you are experiencing.

Comment: Yes both conditions are being met this is very odd to me I can show you a video of it not working if you'd like (Both conditions being freezetime > 0 and the tag being compared to freezing) The debug.log is running for both

Comment: is running* no for both

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not in fact the animator or the scripts being set to false but it was actually because I had started a wait function but it started the wait function and immediately ran the code that was supposed to go after the wait function.
TLDR; waited but the code ran anyway.
If you want the completed working code here it is. The spacing is a little weird because of stackoverflow btw:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyHealth : MonoBehaviour
{
public float health;

public float freezeTime;
public Animator anim;
public Enemy script;
public Rigidbody2D rb;
public bool WaitOver;
// Start is called before the first frame update
IEnumerator Wait(){
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (freezeTime);
    WaitOver = true;
    Debug.Log("waiting over");
}
void Start()
{
    anim = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
    script = gameObject.GetComponent<Enemy>();
    rb = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if(health <= 0){
        Dead();
    }   
    if (WaitOver == true){
            
        anim.SetBool("IsFrozen", false);
        gameObject.GetComponent<Enemy>().enabled = true;
        rb.isKinematic = false;
    }
}
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other){
    if(other.CompareTag("Harmful")){
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
        TakeDamage();
    }
    if(other.CompareTag("Freezing")){
         WaitOver = false; 
         anim.SetBool("IsFrozen", true); 
         rb.isKinematic = true;
         Destroy(other.gameObject);
         GetComponent<Enemy>().enabled = false;
         TakeDamage();
         Debug.Log("waiting started");
         StartCoroutine(Wait());
         
    }
}
void TakeDamage(){
     health -= 1f;
}
void Dead(){
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

}